# Bootstrap dropdown login menu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate a dropdown sign in menu into a bootstrap template. Below is my code for the template page and the sign in menu which should be appearing when the log in button is pressed in the right of the navigation bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="bootstrap/favicon.ico">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="margin:6px 0px"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lr animated slideInRight" role="menu">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h3><b>Log In</b></h3>
                                </div>
                                <form id="ajax-login-form" action="" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-7">
                                                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="remember" id="remember">
                                                <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" class="hide" name="token" id="token" value="a465a2791ae0bae853cf4bf485dbe1b6">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are the paths to the bootstrap css and js correct?

Comment: Prblem is not clear. Your code is working at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLwPYd. Check you added bootstrap correctly.

Comment: Yes all working fine

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: In my page when the login button is pressed it isn't showing. All links to bootstrap files are correct and the codepen link above shows the code I posted working fine but it isn't working in my webpage.

Comment: use this link and put the cdn links for the bootstrap like you did for jQuery...https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Replaced with those links and still experiencing the problem.